# Back and Next Button in a Custom list

Tags: custom-list

I have a Custom list for my Client's Licenses Renewal Alert. I want to be able to navigate between each entry without going back to the main list each time.

Is there a way to add a buttons like PREVIOUS - NEXT?

[image]

Thanks guys!

Seb

Comment: Judging by the screenshot you allready have some custom code, If it is a different display of a View it could be all the items are allready available.

Comment: There is a Preview Pane list view style that allows previewing list items without having to go back to the main list view. It is not exactly prev-next functionality but worth trying if you havn't already.

Comment: @DannyEngelman, yes I use Infowise Pro to customize without the need of intense coding, but I am always ready to add some codes to get where I want.

Comment: @HarryB, I played a little with views. I will definitely give it more time, thanks!